# Which eigenvectors should I ignore?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Solving an [Euler-Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory) for a beam using [Finite Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) leads to the following equation
$$M \ddot{\vec d}(t)+K \vec d(t)=\vec F$$
where $M$ is system mass matrix, $K$ system stiffness matrix and $\vec d(t)$ a vector of primary node variables.
In my case where we discreticise the beam to $n=5$ identical parts (see attached figure)[image] the vector of primary variables can be written as follows $$\vec d (t)=(w_1,\Phi_1,w_2,\Phi_2,w_3,\Phi_3,w_4,\Phi_4,w_5,\Phi_5,w_6,\Phi_6)^\intercal$$ assuming $w_i$ is the vertical displacement of $i$-th node and $\Phi_i$ the angle at $i$-th node.

Note that the $dim(\vec d(t))=12$, therefore both mass and stiffness matrices are 12$\times$12 matrices.

It is also obvious from the attached figure that $\vec F =\vec 0$, since we do not have any external forces or momentums acting on the beam. In that case the dynamic equation can be rewritten to
$$-\omega_0^2 M\vec d(t)+K\vec d(t)=\vec 0,$$
where I already assumed that the system will respond harmonically ($\ddot{\vec d}(t)=-\omega_0^2\vec d(t)$). Now what we have here is eigensystem
$$(M^{-1}K-\omega_0^2)\vec d(t)=\vec 0$$

THE PROBLEM:
Let's assume that we were able to calculate all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the system (meaning we were able to get some numerical values). Now what I would like to do is I would like to visualize the displacements of each node - $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, $w_4$, $w_5$ and $w_6$.

But I have 12 eigenvectors each with dimension of 12. Meaning I would have to somehow ignore half of the eigenvectors. But... How do I know which ones?

EXAMPLE:
Let's say that one of the eigenvectors is $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)$. According to how we defined $\vec d(t)$ I would like to get components $(1,3,5,7,9,11)$. But which eigenvectors do I choose?

Comment: crosspost on physics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289451/58382